# How to update a nested array field inside another nested array in mongo DB using Mongoose Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There is a document that has a nested array inside a nested array. In one of the cases, I want to update the child array of child array.

```
    {
        "_id": "62da8472669b750870b094f6",
        "name": "Test Expert",
        "user_id": "62bdabee9aa50c0028d60767",
        "services": [
            {
                "service_name": "Hello 2",
                "service_id": "62ce7393534bda04d40f42c3",
                "_id": "62ce7394534bda04d40f42c4",
                "videos": [
                    {
                        "_id": "62da8472669b750870b094f8",
                        "lv_guid_id": "fsdfdshflsdhj",
                        "status": "REQUESTED" //Need to update this element status
                    },
 {
                        "_id": "62da8472669b750870b09sdw",
                        "lv_guid_id": "gdfgdfgfdg",
                        "status": "REQUESTED" //Need to update this element status
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
```

In this above document, I want to update the element inside `videos` array and this `videos` array are nested array of `services` array.

This is what I tried but I couldn't get the second nested array position.

```
 this.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(orderID), "services._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(videoDetail.service_id), "services.videos.lv_guid_id": videoDetail.lv_guid_id },
    {
      $set: {
        "services.$.videos./*Need to fetch the position of this element to update*/.status": videoDetail.status
      }
    },
    { upsert: true, new: true }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `arrayFilters` condition,

- create a variable `v` and check the condition for `lv_guid_id`

```
this.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(orderID), 
    "services._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(videoDetail.service_id)
  },
  {
    $set: { "services.$.videos.$[v].status": videoDetail.status }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [{ "v.lv_guid_id": videoDetail.lv_guid_id }],
    upsert: true,
    new: true
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D0d8s-0vr3h)

> Note: you can not upsert sub document/array element

Comment: Thanks, It works well. Is there any option to update all the element at once?

Comment: you can use `$[]` like `"services.$.videos.$[].status": videoDetail.status`.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is `"services.$.videos.$.status"` if I get you right. Give it a try.

```
this.findOneAndUpdate(
    {  _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(orderID), "services._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(videoDetail.service_id), "services.videos.lv_guid_id": videoDetail.lv_guid_id },
    { $set: { "services.$.videos.$.status": videoDetail.status } },
    { new: true },
)
```

Comment: It can not allow too many positional `$` operators in the update.

Comment: You can use it with arrayfilters and `$[]` operator.